# jumping to a certain point in the video

Tags: javascript, laravel

while using laravel 5 and google chrome to return the view that include a video tag 
  I can't get to allow video seeking I found that it could relate to not 
  accepting range in laravel but being quite noob I don't know what to do??

```
     <!-- the view -->
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
     </head>
      <body>
        <div id="app">
            <video id="xx" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered"
            data-setup={} height="300px" width="300px" 
            preload="none"  controls>
             <source src="{{asset('videos/property.mp4#t=120')}}" 
             type="video/mp4" media="" >
             </video>
         </div>
      </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) as a video player. This is where you'll be able to handle scrubbing and jumping to a timestamp within the video. I'd check their documentation for the best way to handle that, and look at your Google Chrome dev tools console to see if there are any JavaScript errors.

There isn't currently a non-JavaScript way to start a video at a specified point, so I don't believe Laravel is the culprit here.

Comment: if I just do the same in firefox it works without me doing anything and the same if I use PHP core, that's why I think I missed something while using Laravel  that's all what happens in chrome it resets the currentTime to zero every time I try to jump in time